# How to view history of queries (all OR over a long period) performed on database which is hosted on Azure?

Tags: logging, azure, indexing, azure-sql-database, database-tuning

For a database hosted on Azure, i can view the recent history of the queries performed on it. This is through the **Azure portal > Database > Manage > Administration > Query Performance**.

Unfortunately, the history found there, only covers a small time frame (few minutes). I intend to create non-clustered indexes on my database and for that, need to get a log of the real queries run on the data on a typical day, as opposed to the past few minutes.

Currently, i have to keep refreshing the page many times and record all the queries for each refresh, Even then, the log which i obtain after this arduous process, only reflects a small subset of the queries performed. Is there any option to view histories for longer periods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a query I found useful to see the most executed queries on my Azure SQL Server database:

```
SELECT TOP 10 execution_count, statement_text
FROM (
    SELECT QS.*,
    SUBSTRING(
        ST.text,
        (QS.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
        ((
            CASE statement_end_offset
            WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
            ELSE QS.statement_end_offset END
            - QS.statement_start_offset
        ) /2) 
        + 1
    ) AS statement_text
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS QS
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) as ST
) AS query_stats
WHERE statement_text LIKE 'UPDATE%'
ORDER BY execution_count DESC
```

Source: [March Madness - SQL Azure - sys.dm_exec_query_plan | SQLRockstar | Thomas LaRock](https://thomaslarock.com/2012/03/march-madness-sql-azure-sys-dm_exec_query_stats/)

Answer (score 7):

Windows Azure SQL Database offers dynamic management views (DMVs) that return server state information that can be used to monitor the health of a server instance, diagnose problems, and tune performance.

For a list of available views refer to [System Views (Windows Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336238.aspx).

For examples of how to find CPU-intensive queries, long-running queries and I/O intensive queries refer to [Tuning SQL Azure Databases, Part 2](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/businessanalytics/tuning-sql-azure-databases-part-2/).

For additional troubleshooting tips refer to [Troubleshoot and Optimize Queries with Windows Azure SQL Database](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1104.troubleshoot-and-optimize-queries-with-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx), [Improving Your I/O Performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/07/27/10043069.aspx), [Gaining Performance Insight into Windows Azure SQL Database](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1657.gaining-performance-insight-into-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx), [Troubleshooting Windows Azure SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee730906.aspx), [Finding Blocking Queries in SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/13/10049896.aspx), [March Madness – SQL Azure – sys.dm_exec_query_stats](http://thomaslarock.com/2012/03/march-madness-sql-azure-sys-dm_exec_query_stats/).

Also consider profiling at the application level, for instance as explained in [Profiling Database Activity in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx) and [Query Profiling SQL Azure when using Entity Framework or Linq-to-SQL](http://huagati.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/query-profiling-sql-azure-when-using.html).

For advanced monitoring consider deploying [Windows Azure SQL Database Management Pack for System Center 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38829).