# How to log all query events in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have set up a SQL Database and enabled the activity log (with a storage account and log analytics workspace). Is there a way within Azure to be able to view realtime or near-realtime queries from the SQL Server? I'm not interested in a performance hit or anything -- now I'm just looking to log all queries so I can make sure that applications are running properly. Here are the resources I have set up:

[image]

I am looking to be able to see a history of all queries that have executed and not just "slow queries" or "currently-running queries", etc.. How can I view queries that are executed, or is this not possible inside Azure?

Here is an example from AWS (RDS + Cloudwatch) where I can do it out of the box:

[image]

Comment: Is is an Azure SQL Database or SQL Server on Azure? If the latter, look at Extended Events.

Comment: Azure SQL Database has Extended Events too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/xevent-db-diff-from-svr

Comment: @Larnu how can I find out? I know the server name shows something like david.database.windows.net, and I created it on Azure.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I see -- so there's no built in way to get a query log? I found this, which gives a SQL query to run: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920968/how-to-view-history-of-queries-all-or-over-a-long-period-performed-on-database#:~:text=For%20a%20database%20hosted%20on,Manage%20%3E%20Administration%20%3E%20Query%20Performance. The first answer has a few broken links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview) or [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/xevent-db-diff-from-svr) using the "Query Batch Tracking" template to capture queries.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to view the blob storage files outside of SSMS?